# eclipse formatting new lines at each method property

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-formatter

How can I set up eclipse formatter, to format a method-body to this:

```java
// I want to have a new line on each method property:
public void test(
    double a, 
    double b, 
    String c, 
    Object f
) {
    a = 4;
    b= 3;
    c = "hello";
    f = null;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new Eclipse **formatter profile based on the *Eclipse [built-in]*** profile and change the following:

- In the ***Line Wrapping*** tab, choose ***Method Declarations > Parameters***:

  - Set ***Line wrapping policy*** to ***Wrap all elements, every element on a new line***
  - Check ***Force split, even if line is shorter than maximum line width***
  - Set ***Indentaton policy*** to ***Indent by one***
- In the ***Parentheses*** tab, set ***Method declaration*** to ***Separate lines***

Comment: thanks. After the settings, the preview within "eclipse formatter window" shows the method declaration exactly what I wanted. I saved and use this template, then I mark the method, pressed "Shift+Alt+N": It formats the source with the "Force split" but does not do the "Line wrapping policy" (all method parameters are shown in a new line (but at the same line). However, the preview window shows the correct way.

Comment: I tested with Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) and it works without problems. Make sure the active workspace formatter profile (_Window > Preferences: Java > Code Style > Formatter_) is not overridden by the project formatter profile (_Project > Properteis: Java Code Style > Formatter_). By default, the shortcut for _Source > Format_ is Ctrl+Shif+F.

Comment: yes, it works. had not saved the actual profile. thanks!